# Ubuntu 16.04 How to use Ethernet captive portals

Tags: networking

I'm running 16.04 still and need to connect via internet to my campus network. However they use a captive portal login that works fine in windows, but Ubuntu doesn't like. Every browser I try gives me an error when the portal is trying to redirect me to itself. Historically I never have been able to get a captive portal to work on Linux - anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue with 16.04 and Linux-unfriendly captive portals, possibly fixed since 17.10 but I'm unsure and can't test it. Meanwhile, if you can't upgrade or try with the latests Ubuntu versions, use the `route` command in terminal.

```
$ sudo route
```

You should see something like:

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination  Gateway   Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref Use Iface
default      10.0.2.2  0.0.0.0        UG     600     0   0   wlan0
10.0.2.2     *         255.255.248.0  U      600     0   0   wlan0
link-local   *         255.255.0.0    U      1000    0   0   wlan0
```

Type the gateway adress in your browser (here: 10.0.2.2), this should get you to the captive portal page. Try with different browsers if necessary.